# vb.net get the original key of a sorted value

Tags: vb.net

I'm a student. Can someone help me with my project using vb.net 2010, it is possible to the original value of a variable that is sorted.
This is my code:

```
Dim Done As Boolean = False
        Dim Over As Boolean = False
        Dim num1 As Single = Single.Parse(Main.Bbt.Text)
        Dim num2 As Single = Single.Parse(Main.Cbt.Text)
        Dim num3 As Single = Single.Parse(Main.Dbt.Text)
        Do While Not Done
            Done = True
            If num1 > num2 Then Swap(num1, num2) : Done = False
            If num1 > num3 Then Swap(num1, num3) : Done = False
            If num2 > num3 Then Swap(num2, num3) : Done = False
        Loop
        v2.Text = (Val(v1.Text)) + (num1.ToString)
        v2.Width = (15 * Val(v1.Text)) + (15 * num1.ToString) + 4
        t2.Width = (15 * Val(v1.Text)) + (15 * num1.ToString)
        t2.Visible = True
        If Single.Parse(num1) = (Main.Bbt.Text) Then
            t2.Text = "B"
        ElseIf Single.Parse(num1) = (Main.Cbt.Text) Then
            t2.Text = "C"
        Else
            t2.Text = "D"
        End If
```

For example how to find the original value num1 which is Main.Bbt.Text, with this code i get an output with same letters if they have same values.

```
If num1 = Main.Bbt.Text Then
            t2.Text = "B"
        ElseIf num1 = Main.Cbt.Text Then
            t2.Text = "C"
        Else
            t2.Text = "D"
        End If
If num2 = Main.Bbt.Text Then
            t3.Text = "B"
        ElseIf num2 = Main.Cbt.Text Then
            t3.Text = "C"
        Else
            t3.Text = "D"
        End If
If num3 = Main.Bbt.Text Then
            t4.Text = "B"
        ElseIf num3 = Main.Cbt.Text Then
            t4.Text = "C"
        Else
            t4.Text = "D"
        End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using reference types, specifically nullable types, as you're using Single, which is a value type.

If you use a swap function like this:

```
Sub Swap(ByRef A As SingleValue, ByRef B As SingleValue)
    Dim C = A
    A = B
    B = C
End Sub
```

and a class to store the values like this:

```
Class SingleValue
    Public Shared Widening Operator CType(ByVal Value As Single) As SingleValue
        Return New SingleValue(Value)
    End Operator

    Public Shared Widening Operator CType(ByVal Value As SingleValue) As Single
        Return Value.Value
    End Operator

    Public Shared Operator >(ByVal A As SingleValue, ByVal B As SingleValue) As Boolean
        Return A.Value > B.Value
    End Operator

    Public Shared Operator <(ByVal A As SingleValue, ByVal B As SingleValue) As Boolean
        Return A.Value < B.Value
    End Operator

    Public Sub New(ByVal Value As Single)
        Me.Value = Value
    End Sub

    Public Value As Single
End Class
```

and do like this:

```
Dim num1 As SingleValue = Single.Parse(Main.Bbt.Text)
Dim num2 As SingleValue = Single.Parse(Main.Cbt.Text)
Dim num3 As SingleValue = Single.Parse(Main.Dbt.Text)
Dim num1Original = num1
Dim num2Original = num2
Dim num3Original = num3
```

and like this:

```
If num1 = num1Original Then
    t2.Text = "B"
ElseIf num1 = num2Original Then
    t2.Text = "C"
Else
    t2.Text = "D"
End If
If num2 = num1Original Then
    t3.Text = "B"
ElseIf num2 = num2Original Then
    t3.Text = "C"
Else
    t3.Text = "D"
End If
If num3 = num1Original Then
    t4.Text = "B"
ElseIf num3 = num2Original Then
    t4.Text = "C"
Else
    t4.Text = "D"
End If
```

I belive you'll get what you want (from what I understand of your explanation).

When value types are copied, they are usually copied by value, instead of by reference. Value types can be wrapped into reference types by defining your own class. When comparing value types only the values are compared, not whether they are the same copy of the same value. When comparing reference types the comparison may be by value or by reference depending on the operators defined. In this case, they are being compared by reference when using the equality (=) operator. You can also use the Is operator to force comparison by reference (but this still only works for reference types).